# Ubuntu doesn't detect hard drive in laptop Acer Aspire 3

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, suspend, acer

I've seen this question multiple times in here, but none of the answers were helpful to me. Basically, I've managed to install Ubuntu on mi laptop (along with Windows 10), but I cannot boot it because, like the title says, my Ubuntu partition doesn't detect the hard drive (the Windows partition works perfectly). The only way that Ubuntu can see the disks is by suspending/sleeping the laptop for a few seconds and waking it up, then it works fine. So I need a way to put the computer to sleep before booting, or something like it. Is there a way to do this?
To be clear, I've already tried several things: change SATA mode to AHCI, disabled fast boot and secure boot, edit the boot config file by adding something like "test_suspend=mem", among others. Nothing worked.

Comment: in what way does it "not detect the hard drive"? how do you ever boot into it to know that it detects the drive when you suspend+wake it?

Comment: because when I was installing from a live USB, the installer didn't let me do it because it only detected the USB itself, not the hard drive. then i canceled the instalation and closed the window, so i could only "try" ubuntu, without installing it. it was then when i put the laptop to sleep and after waking it up, tried again to install and the hard drive was "magically" detected and i was able to install ubuntu. basically, this is exactly what happens to me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox

Comment: @did you try the steps in that question?

Comment: yes, but it didn't help

Comment: Did you turn on Secure Boot, set password & then enable "trust". Best to remove password or never ever forget it. You may want Secure Boot back off. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947

Comment: yes, i've just tried that, didn't work 

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) on new Acer Aspire 3 A317-53 laptop computers

Read and experienced various frustrating problems of installing Ubuntu on PCs without AHCI setting (especially new PCs with SSD hard drives) myself before.  I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) on new Acer Aspire3 A317-53 laptop computers along side Windows 11 and surprisingly no issue at all throughout the installation process.  Now I have dual boot for two such PCs successfully.  Maybe 22.04 LTS is a solution by itself now.  Hope this helps.

1. The BIOS of Acer Aspire3 A317-53 laptop computer no longer allows you to have AHCI setting, no matter what you do (Booting Windows in safe mode, BIOS password, Ctrl+S, ets.)
2. I did the following changes in the BIOS before configuring Windows 11 after I bought the PCs.
3. Start up the PC and immediately press Fn+F2 to get into BIOS (not just F2, default is in special function mode).
4. Go to Security menu and set supervisor password.
5. Go to Main menu and press Ctrl+S to enable hidden setting (only adding VDM controller and touchpad options, nothing else).  Enable F12 for boot menu option.  Disable Fast Boot option.  Change the Function  key mode (so that I don’t need to press Fn key to use F2 or F12).
6. Go to Boot menu.  Disable Security Boot option.  UEFI mode is already in default.
7. Save the new setting and exit BIOS.  Let the PC boot into Windows 11.
8. Configure Windows 11 (this is where I tried the Window Safe Mode and change BIOS again only to find out no way to get to AHCI option).
9. Use Windows Disk Manager to shrink the C-drive and open up 150GB unallocated space for Ubuntu installation.  Reboot the PC to make sure Windows 11 runs normal.  Shut down the PC.
10. Download Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and make a boot up USB drive of it.
11. Boot the PC and immediately press F12 key to go to boot menu.  Select boot from the USB.
12. Install Ubuntu 22.04, wifi automatically detected, hard drive and all partitions found.
13. I select “Something else” in the installation type option.  In the partition table I choose the free 150GB space previously opened up by Windows and create a new ext4 partition to give this space all to root(/) mount point.  Accept all other installation settings.
14. Installation completed successfully.  Reboot and the dual-boot grub menu appears.  Everything works well as expected!